# What happens to momentum when a car crashes into a barrier?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, reference-frames, conservation-laws, collision

The law of conservation of momentum states that the total momentum in a closed system is conserved.

When a car crashes into a barrier, the barrier and the car may crumple but the car will come to a stop. How exactly is the initial momentum of the car conserved?

Comment: The barrier is anchored to the Earth, so when you hit it, the Earth moves very, very slightly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is momentum conserved in this situation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/285715/)

Comment: Remember, the car got it's momentum by "borrowing" it from Earth in the first place.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/132605/25301 (and the "Linked" column on the right)

Answer (score 2):

I would answer that very differently, because momentum cannot be converted to sound, heat, or deformation.  What actually happens is the same thing that would happen if a rock with the same momentum as the car hit the Earth a glancing blow and got stuck: it would change the earth's rotation and orbital velocity by an infinitesimal amount -- just enough to make sure the net angular and linear momentum do not change.